# How to export or save a plane mesh as image format in three.js or webgl

Tags: javascript, image, three.js

Suppose I have created a mesh with plane geometry and have multiple effects on it.

```
var tx = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("g.png");
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        //color: 0x00ff00,  
        map:tx,
        //wireframe: true
        side:THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    material.needsUpdate=true;
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(g, material);
```

Now I want the plane to be exported or saved as image format like .png etc. Is it possible or have to "prntScr" only.

Comment: You can get the whole scene as an image: `renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` I don't know if it's that what you want?

Comment: thanks for reply. but that I know also same thing can be done with prntScr...but I need the particular mesh/plane

Comment: you can only print the canvas and crop it.

Comment: I tried other things and not worked. I think this is the only way as of now. Thanks all.